# Weird compile error in Eclipse and Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting an error : **Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens**, on valid Java code

[image]

My code, copied and pasted from eclipse, is here :

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

I am guessing that there is some hidden character in the code which I can't see.
I tried restarting Eclipse, and cleaning the project, but the error is still there!

Even if I copy and paste this code from SO into eclipse the error is still there!

what is going on here?

**EDIT**

Its not Eclipse! In Netbeans I get the same error :

[image]

Also, the original problem occurred when I tried to copy and paste code examples from this webpage  http://blue-walrus.com/2011/05/advanced-swing-multithreading-tutorial/

Comment: Just try to delete all the (underlines) whitespcace and see if this is causing it. Might be a non-breaking space or similiar. If you open it with a hex editor, you will see.

Comment: I don't see any invisible unicode character using [C# in depth : unicode explorer](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer)

Comment: Copy/paste the message in the _Problem view_ or display invisible characters with the _Show Whitespace Characters_ button (it is hidden by default, but you can access it in the _Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editor > Show Whitespace Characters_).

Comment: what is problem view

Comment: Try menu Project > Clean...

Comment: Sometimes the UI fails to update when the code changes.

Comment: The problem view is an UI which list all problems that spawn across your source code (like compilation errors, warnings, etc).

Comment: Presumably it's not a Java project. If you right click the project Properties do you see "Java Build Path" and does it show a valid "JRE System Library"? and do you also have the "Source" folders listed also under "Java Build Path"

Comment: Just try to write a valid java code line into the `main()`-method. I often have those error messages, and they disappear after changing the code

Answer (score 1):

I just did the following:

1. Cut and paste the code from your Question to a file and compiled it using `javac` (Java 8).  No compilation errors.
2. Opened Eclipse (Kepler), created a `Test2` class, copied the code from the Question to it, and saved it.  No compilation errors.

My tentative conclusion is that there is nothing wrong with the java code.  (No funky hidden characters, no nasty homoglyphs, no messed up character encodings.)  The most likely cause of these weird errors is that your Eclipse session is messed up:

- Try restarting Eclipse.
- Try closing and opening the Project.
- Try loading your code into a fresh workspace.
- In extremis ... try a fresh install of Eclipse (same version as before ...)

Comment: i dont think its that. I just installed Netbeans and i get the same compile errors.

Comment: In that case, when you copied the code to StackOverflow, something must have changed those strange control characters into ... something else.  Anyway, you have solved your problem.  You know that you have weird control characters in the files ... and replacing them with kosher white-space will make the errors go away.

Comment: yes. StackOverflow scrubbed the problem characters away. An Outlook Email also seemed to work for me.#

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comments your project must have a valid JDK and JRE defined

[image]

[image]

If these are missing from your project, go to `Window > Preferences> Java Installed JREs` and click `Add..`

[image]

If you make any changes select `Project > Clean...` again

Comment: its not eclipse. It also happens in Netbeans. it seems to be some weird white space character. SO cleaned my question up so you probably don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

To remove these strange hidden empty space characters, I copy and pasted into Outlook Email, and then copy and pasted into Notepad++, and then copied into Eclipse. All fixed :)

Seems you need to copy and paste situations like this through a few different apps, to 'scrub' the text of any funny characters.

Comment: Just use basic "Notepad" and save as a new *.txt file

Answer (score 0):

I think the java class path is not set in your computer if that is the case go to my computer->properties->Advanced System settings->Advanced tab click Environment variables find variable path & check if the java class path is there. If its not there i suggest you to copy the java class path & edit variable path & paste the url followed by ";" & then restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

better to check your project build path i.e, JRE system library version/is that set or not in the eclipse

way to go for properties section of eclipse :

right click on project - > choose properties ->build path->Libraries->Add Library Variable->JRE system library->click Add alternate JRE radio button->and select your machine jre->click finish->OK

after that go for java compiler in the same window (left side)->check the enable project settings->and choose your java version from drop down box->click Apply->OK

finally save your program and run it

if it again fails you need to check whether you are setting the classpath in proper or not, for this 
please refer this link to set classpath :[Link](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/11/29/set-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-java/)

Answer (score 0):

## [ZWSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) and other non-printing characters

Means a Zero-Width-Space character. You are using UTF8 and some characters have a width of 0 so you can not see them.

Change the Encoding to ANSI and back will solve your Problem.